# NodeJS - Restart aplication at given time

Tags: node.js

I have made my speech recognizer server with nodejs, but it happens that I have a tiny memory leak in each recognition that is driving me crazy. While I am fixing this problem I want to use the actual version. To do that I am thinking in a routine, that restarts the nodejs at given time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend fixing the memory leak so it doesn't slide - but in the meantime you can use [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) in your code to reload itself. You would basically have to wrap forever around your entire application.

Comment: Could be better solution than batch file?

Comment: I am not understanding how this can be implemented. Can you be more specific? @Svenskunganka

Answer (score 1):

try nodemon

```
npm install -g nodemon --save
```

then start ur app as `nodemon app.js`

Comment: sry if u meant something else in ur question

Answer (score 0):

This can accomplish part of almost of I want. Using .bat file, the one possible solution could be:

```
@echo off
REM nodevars.bat directory
:loop
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs 
call nodevars.bat 
::PAUSE
cd C:\app_directory
::PAUSE 
REM Initialize nodejs server
start node app.js
::node app.js ::equivalent
REM do the timeout
timeout /t 5 > null REM 5 seconds
taskkill /f /im node.exe >null
REM safety close
timeout /t 2 >null REM 2 Seconds
goto loop
```